# How to preserve newlines in CDATA when generating XML?

Tags: java, xml, newline, w3c, cdata

I want to write some text that contains whitespace characters such as `newline` and `tab` into an xml file so I use

```
Element element = xmldoc.createElement("TestElement");
element.appendChild(xmldoc.createCDATASection(somestring));
```

but when I read this back in using

```
Node vs =  xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("TestElement").item(0);
String x = vs.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

I get a string that has no newlines anymore.
When i look directly into the xml on disk, the newlines seem preserved. so the problem occurs when reading in the xml file.

How can I preserve the newlines?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a more complete code example?

Comment: it is a Element. i will post more code soon.

Comment: when you get the value of 'x', it is equivalent to 'somestring' minus the newlines?

Comment: have you tried escaping the backslash on your `\n` to make it `\\n`?

Comment: well, when i look directly into the xml on disk, the newlines seem preserved. so the problem occurs when reading in the xml. sorry i didnt tell this earlier. i will add it to my post.

Comment: What newline character is being used? A shot in the dark, but I wonder if it has something to do with how newlines are supported: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends

Comment: @McDowll, how can i find out what newline character is used?
i have the xmlfile on disk, where the newline look fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you parse and write your document, but here's an enhanced code example based on yours:

```
// creating the document in-memory                                                        
Document xmldoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

Element element = xmldoc.createElement("TestElement");                                    
xmldoc.appendChild(element);                                                              
element.appendChild(xmldoc.createCDATASection("first line\nsecond line\n"));              

// serializing the xml to a string                                                        
DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();             

DOMImplementationLS impl =                                                                
    (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");                             

LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();                                          
String str = writer.writeToString(xmldoc);                                                

// printing the xml for verification of whitespace in cdata                               
System.out.println("--- XML ---");                                                        
System.out.println(str);                                                                  

// de-serializing the xml from the string                                                 
final Charset charset = Charset.forName("utf-16");                                        
final ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(charset));       
Document xmldoc2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);

Node vs =  xmldoc2.getElementsByTagName("TestElement").item(0);                           
final Node child = vs.getFirstChild();                                                    
String x = child.getNodeValue();                                                          

// print the value, yay!                                                                  
System.out.println("--- Node Text ---");                                                  
System.out.println(x);
```

The serialization using LSSerializer is the W3C way to do it ([see here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-3)). The output is as expected, with line separators:

```
--- XML --- 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<TestElement><![CDATA[first line
second line ]]></TestElement>
--- Node Text --- 
first line
second line
```

Comment: thank you, i tried that but it doesnt work for me. while i can see the linebreaks are there in the xmlfile on disk, once i read them back with this code, they are gone. maybe my linebreak character is bad. how can i find out, which one it is?

Comment: The output I showed is a real output from my own machine of the code example I posted.
Did you try writing the text with the code I suggested? Or only to read it using my code?
Also, what is the encoding of your file (you can see that in my example, the encoding is UTF-16). I had a similar problem by not using the same encoding, and I fixed it by using Charset.forName() with the actual encoding used.

Comment: yep, i did try your actual code in my case. i used exactly the same code to output the string. but it does not contain whitespaces. the encoding i use is encoding="ISO-8859-1" i will try to use UTF-16

Comment: If you use exactly the same code with ISO-8859-1, you will have problems - unless you change the Charset.forName to use ISO-8859-1.
New-lines can be problematic between ASCII and UTF-16, so its worth a shot.

Comment: I have tried with "utf-16" while de-serializing, but in my case .. it is converting "\r\n" with "\n\n" which cause issue to me. Can you please provide solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the type of each node using node.getNodeType(). If the type is CDATA_SECTION_NODE, you need to concat the CDATA guards to node.getNodeValue.

Comment: yes, the type of the node is CDATA. but what do you mean with concat CDATA guards?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to use CDATA to preserve white space characters.
The XML [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends)  specify how to encode these characters.

So for example, if you have an element with value that contains new space you should encode it with

```
  &#xA;
```

Carriage return:

```
 &#xD;
```

And so forth

Comment: thanks, but is there a way without encoding it? so that i can see the formatted text in the xml file itself?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: cut all the irrelevant stuff

I'm curious to know what DOM implementation you're using, because it doesn't mirror the default behaviour of the one in a couple of JVMs I've tried (they ship with a Xerces impl). I'm also interested in what newline characters your document has.

I'm not sure if whether CDATA should preserve whitespace is a given. I suspect that there are many factors involved. Don't DTDs/schemas affect how whitespace is processed?

You could try using the xml:space="preserve" attribute.

Comment: thanks, where exactly should i add that xml:space="preserve" attribute? to the node that contains the text or to the xml root?

Answer (score 0):

xml:space='preserve' is not it. That is only for "all whitespace" nodes. That is, if you want the whitespace nodes in

```
<this xml:space='preserve'> <has/>
<whitespace/>
</this>
```

But see that those whitespace nodes are ONLY whitespace.

I have been struggling to get Xerces to generate events allowing isolation of CDATA content as well. I have no solution as yet.